# Does huggingface have a model that is based on word-level tokens?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I'm trying to do token classification, but interested in doing it for word-level and not sub-words/etc.

I currently have:

```
models_name = 'distilbert-base-cased'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(models_name, model_max_length=512, truncation=True, padding=True)
token_classification_model = AutoModelForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(models_name, num_labels=4).to(device)
```

But this is on a sub-word level

Answer (score 0):

The HuggingFace Hub has several loose word-level tokenizer checkpoints/models, however if you are looking for a strict word-level tokenizer then you may not have readily available checkpoints/models. You may have to rely on external libraries instead.

**1. Strict word-level tokenizers**

- The simplest form would be  splitting on whitespace or/and punctuation and then passing it to models such as **Word2vec**. You may want to consider using an alternative library such as **gensim**, which provides a robust and well-documented implementation of the word2vec algorithm instead.
- At the time of this writing, the HuggingFace hub has a few user hosted word2vec checkpoints such as this: https://huggingface.co/vocab-transformers/distilbert-word2vec_256k-MLM_best.

**2. Loose word-level tokenizers**

The idea here is that the tokenizer would first tokenize at the word level by default because it expects the input as a word (in its base form) by default and then falls back on lower levels (syntactically and semantically, e.g. sub-word, byte-level, character level) to account for additional processing which includes handling unknow or out of vocabulary words. Processing word at each level of granularity will have its own tokenizer algorithm specification.

The complete taxonomy of the available HuggingFace Tokenizers is as follows:

- Character Level BPE, e.g. NMT, GPT
- Byte-Level, e.g. BPE GPT-2, RoBerta
- WordPiece, e.g. BERT
- SentencePiece, e.g. XLNet
- Unigram, e.g. LM
- Character, e.g.Reformer
- Custom, e.g. Bio-Chem

Ref: https://aclanthology.org/2020.emnlp-demos.6.pdf

**You must also keep in mind that The tokenizer and model should always be from the same checkpoint.**

For example:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")

encoded = tokenizer("Hello!", return_tensors="np")
result = model(**encoded)
```

Here using gpt2 with bert-base-cased wouldn't yield desired results even though theoretically bert-base-cased is an encoder model. The model was just not trained to make sense out of this tokenizer's output however, so the model output will not make any sense and it may not even run!

Similarly, you may want to consider and experiment appropriate tokenizers for the distilbert-base-cased model as stated in your example for the token classification task.

Ref: https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter2/8?fw=pt

Answer (score 0):

Even though recent language models use tokeniser which may split words into sub-tokens, this doesn't mean that you can't use them to perform token-level classification. In fact, the [BERT paper](https://aclanthology.org/N19-1423/) includes Named-Entity Recognition as one of its tasks.

The problem is how to choose a single classification for a word from multiple classifications for each sub-token. A simple (& common) approach is to simply take the classification made on the first sub-token, ignoring the rest of the sub-tokens. In fact this is what's shown in the [Hugging Face documentation for token classification](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/tasks/token_classification) when training the model. Basing off of this, you could extract the tokens that you are interested in:

```py
text = "Lorem ipsum"
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")
with torch.no_grad():
    logits = model(**inputs).logits

labels = []
previous_word_id = None
for i, word_id in enumerate(inputs.word_ids()):
    if word_id is not None and word_id != previous_word_id:
            labels.append(model.config.id2label[torch.argmax(logits[0][i]).item()])
    previous_word_id = word_id
```

The above code uses the [`word_ids`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__.is_split_into_words) which groups sub-tokens by words. This will probably suffice in most cases, but you are free to use a different notion of what a word is, in which case you'll probably need to use [`is_split_into_words`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__.is_split_into_words) when tokenizing.

There are other techniques to use besides picking the first, such as taking the `mean` of all the logits related to a given word, before applying `argmax`. However, I suggest keeping it simple unless you really need to.